# Visual debugging for Direct3D/OpenGL/unity3d applications on windows 7

Tags: debugging, opengl, unity-game-engine, directx, shader

I need to visually debug scene rendering (step-by-step frame rendering) in unity3d (version 5) on Windows 7 64bit. "Visually debug" means that I need to walk through rendering process step-by-step and see what unity does to framebuffer at each step.

Which tools are currently available for that?

Few years ago I've been using PerfHUD for similar tasks, but it looks like it is discontinued? The latest version of perfhud(mentioned on nvidia website) is 6.7 and apparently it is from 2011. Perfkit and nsight does not seem to provide similar feature ('visual debugging") and are instead concerned with cuda performance.

On the web, there's mention of Microsoft PIX, BUT microsoft website mentions that it is replaced by "graphics debugging" feature in Visual Studio 2013. Visual studio 2013, meanwhile, really wants me to upgrade to windows 8 and does not let me use the feature otherwise. (VS express 2013 for windows *desktop* does not have this feature).

So, what else is available? I'm only need to run the tool on my own machine which means Nvidia GPU and windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS 2013 Community or VS 2013 Pro+ Update 4 is the best way to get the modern 'graphics debugging' features from Visual Studio for DirectX 11. The capture engine is much more robust on Windows 8.1 or Windows 10, but will work on Windows 7.

For Direct3D 9, you can still use the legacy PIX for Windows tool.

See [DirectX SDK Tools Catalog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/10/28/directx-sdk-tools-catalog.aspx) and [DirectX 11.1 and Windows 7 Update](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/02/26/directx-11-1-and-windows-7-update.aspx)

Comment: Hmm. That might work, but I need to research licensing restriction for visual studio community edition. I'm not working on opensource app here.

Comment: Definitely check it out. For most people either you quality for the [Community license](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/dn877550.aspx) or your organization should have the money to buy a copy of Pro.

Comment: Well, community edition works (there's a gotcha about being subcontracted though - can't use it if someone BIG hires me for remote work). I also found out that unity has (somewhat limited) "Frame Debugger" that can be used for same purpose. I'll upvote/accept your answer, but you might want to add notice about frame debugger to it - that'll make your answer more useful for other people.

Comment: Also unity has [nice article](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-DebuggingD3D11ShadersWithVS.html) that walks people through shader debugging process.